# SQL Server Between Start and End dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I'm creating an internal holiday booking system and I need to put business logic rules into place but I need to do a check on how many people are booked off on the dates between the Start and End date because for example 2 apprentices may only be booked off on 1 day but I have no way off grabbing the dates between.

Any help would be appreciated

Below is the job role table

[image: JobRoleTable]

Comment: What RDBMS (Oracle, SQL Server 2008R2, SQLLite, etc.) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the RDBMS, or the names of the tables, or what exactly the Job Role table is supposed to be doing ... but I'll take a shot at this anyway. I'm using a recursive CTE to generate a list of dates, but it would be far better for you to use a Date table, and I don't even know whether your RDBMS will support this.  I've also posted the syntax for a table variable below that populates data mimicking your sample.

The final output, naturally, will need to be customized to do whatever you need to do.  This does show you, however, a list of every date when more than one employee is on vacation.  Add extra conditions to the second `JOIN` or to the `WHERE` clause to filter on other things (like JobRole) if necessary.

```
-- Code originally from http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/

-- Define start and end limits
DECLARE @todate DATETIME, @fromdate DATETIME
SELECT @fromdate='2014-01-01', @todate=GETDATE()-1

DECLARE @TimeOff TABLE (StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME, EmployeeID INT)

INSERT INTO @TimeOff (StartDate, EndDate, EmployeeID)
SELECT '1/1/2014', '1/7/2014', 7 UNION 
SELECT '2/1/2014', '2/7/2014', 7 UNION 
SELECT '3/3/2014', '3/9/2014', 7 UNION 
SELECT '2/5/2014', '2/6/2014', 8 

;WITH DateSequence( Date ) AS -- this will list all dates.  Use this if you don't have a date table
  (
    SELECT @fromdate as Date
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date)
    FROM DateSequence
    WHERE Date < @todate
  )

--select result
SELECT DateSequence.Date, TimeOffA.StartDate, TimeOffB.EndDate, TimeOffA.EmployeeID
FROM 
    DateSequence -- a full list of all possible dates
     INNER JOIN 
    @TimeOff TimeOffA ON -- all dates when an employee is on vacation -- replace this with your actual table's name
        DateSequence.Date BETWEEN TimeOffA.StartDate AND TimeOffA.EndDate
     INNER JOIN 
    @TimeOff TimeOffB ON -- all dates when an employee who is NOT employee A is on vacation -- replace this with your actual table's name
        DateSequence.Date BETWEEN TimeOffB.StartDate AND TimeOffB.EndDate AND
        TimeOffA.EmployeeID <> TimeOffB.EmployeeID
option (MaxRecursion 2000)
```